How to easily convert frequency data into raw data (large dataset) for t-test?
Statistics goal: Determine if the difference between two datasets is statistically significant.
Dataset description: The data is available in the form of particle size (mm) v. particle count (frequency) for each sample.
Example:

Problems: I'd like to compare the particle size distributions observed in two samples with a t-test. However, I am unable to conduct the t-test with frequency values. I have tried converting the frequency values into raw data in Excel (using https://real-statistics.com/real-statistics-environment/data-conversion/frequency-table-conversion/). However, using Excel to convert a large dataset is messy and prone to errors. The number of particle sizes listed in the dataset is 802, thus, the raw data (i.e., data with repeating particle sizes) has >802 datapoints.
Possible solutions: My knowledge is limited to plotting tools that come with statistics software (i.e., Excel, SigmaPlot, OriginPro), but I am open to Python or R solutions that would allow me to (a) convert the frequency data into raw data (b) conduct the t-test with less effort.
Thanks!

If I've understood correctly, you could use R to 'expand' the frequency table and then perform the t-test, e.g.
df1 <- data.frame(Particle_size = c(2.009, 2.026, 2.043, 2.06, 2.078),
                 frequency = c(13, 5, 9, 12, 6))
df2 <- data.frame(Particle_size = c(2.009, 2.026, 2.143, 2.06, 2.178),
                  frequency = c(13, 5, 9, 12, 6))
df1
#>   Particle_size frequency
#> 1         2.009        13
#> 2         2.026         5
#> 3         2.043         9
#> 4         2.060        12
#> 5         2.078         6
df2
#>   Particle_size frequency
#> 1         2.009        13
#> 2         2.026         5
#> 3         2.143         9
#> 4         2.060        12
#> 5         2.178         6

# (row 3 and 5 are different in df2)

# Expand the data
df1_expanded <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$frequency), 1:2]
df2_expanded <- df2[rep(seq_len(nrow(df2)), df2$frequency), 1:2]
df1_expanded
#>      Particle_size frequency
#> 1            2.009        13
#> 1.1          2.009        13
#> 1.2          2.009        13
#> 1.3          2.009        13
#> 1.4          2.009        13
#> 1.5          2.009        13
#> 1.6          2.009        13
#> 1.7          2.009        13
#> 1.8          2.009        13
#> 1.9          2.009        13
#> 1.10         2.009        13
#> 1.11         2.009        13
#> 1.12         2.009        13
#> 2            2.026         5
#> 2.1          2.026         5
#> 2.2          2.026         5
#> 2.3          2.026         5
#> 2.4          2.026         5
#> 3            2.043         9
#> 3.1          2.043         9
#> 3.2          2.043         9
#> 3.3          2.043         9
#> 3.4          2.043         9
#> 3.5          2.043         9
#> 3.6          2.043         9
#> 3.7          2.043         9
#> 3.8          2.043         9
#> 4            2.060        12
#> 4.1          2.060        12
#> 4.2          2.060        12
#> 4.3          2.060        12
#> 4.4          2.060        12
#> 4.5          2.060        12
#> 4.6          2.060        12
#> 4.7          2.060        12
#> 4.8          2.060        12
#> 4.9          2.060        12
#> 4.10         2.060        12
#> 4.11         2.060        12
#> 5            2.078         6
#> 5.1          2.078         6
#> 5.2          2.078         6
#> 5.3          2.078         6
#> 5.4          2.078         6
#> 5.5          2.078         6
df2_expanded
#>      Particle_size frequency
#> 1            2.009        13
#> 1.1          2.009        13
#> 1.2          2.009        13
#> 1.3          2.009        13
#> 1.4          2.009        13
#> 1.5          2.009        13
#> 1.6          2.009        13
#> 1.7          2.009        13
#> 1.8          2.009        13
#> 1.9          2.009        13
#> 1.10         2.009        13
#> 1.11         2.009        13
#> 1.12         2.009        13
#> 2            2.026         5
#> 2.1          2.026         5
#> 2.2          2.026         5
#> 2.3          2.026         5
#> 2.4          2.026         5
#> 3            2.143         9
#> 3.1          2.143         9
#> 3.2          2.143         9
#> 3.3          2.143         9
#> 3.4          2.143         9
#> 3.5          2.143         9
#> 3.6          2.143         9
#> 3.7          2.143         9
#> 3.8          2.143         9
#> 4            2.060        12
#> 4.1          2.060        12
#> 4.2          2.060        12
#> 4.3          2.060        12
#> 4.4          2.060        12
#> 4.5          2.060        12
#> 4.6          2.060        12
#> 4.7          2.060        12
#> 4.8          2.060        12
#> 4.9          2.060        12
#> 4.10         2.060        12
#> 4.11         2.060        12
#> 5            2.178         6
#> 5.1          2.178         6
#> 5.2          2.178         6
#> 5.3          2.178         6
#> 5.4          2.178         6
#> 5.5          2.178         6

t.test(df1_expanded$Particle_size, df2_expanded$Particle_size)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  df1_expanded$Particle_size and df2_expanded$Particle_size
#> t = -3.2876, df = 57.154, p-value = 0.001732
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.05363540 -0.01303127
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  2.040489  2.073822

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0
Would this work for your use-case? You can read in the data directly from an excel sheet, or csv file, but without more details it's difficult to help with this first step.
